# BigQuery Date-Partitioned Views

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery allows you to create date-partitioned tables:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

I'd like to be able to create views on top of date-partitioned tables and ideally still reap the performance benefits. Everything I've read suggests that this isn't possible?

Has anyone had any luck otherwise?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Define your view to expose the partitioning pseudocolumn, like this:

```
SELECT *, EXTRACT(DATE FROM _PARTITIONTIME) AS date
FROM Date partitioned table;
```

Now if you query the view using a filter on `date`, it will restrict the partitions that are read.

Comment: Thanks Elliott - if possible, can you point me to any documentation for this?

Comment: I don't think we have anything explicit. I filed an issue on the public tracker that you can follow, though: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63056957.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is only achievable in standard sql and there is no equivalent in legacy sql?

Comment: With legacy SQL, you would need to select the pseudocolumn by itself, e.g. `_PARTITIONTIME AS time`. I would really recommend sticking with standard SQL if you can, though.

Comment: Ah yes. I gave this a try already, but it appears that the query is scanning the whole table from the B processed

Comment: Is it due to one of the [query patterns shown in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#scanning_all_partitions) that result in a full table scan?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of:

`SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    _PARTITIONTIME AS pdate
  FROM
    [dp_test_01] )
WHERE pdate = '20170101
`

Comment: If you are using legacy SQL, it may be providing a less accurate (i.e. higher) estimate before running the query. Using standard SQL should give you the correct bytes scanned prior to running it.

Comment: The B processed shown after having run the query suggest using the legacy sql above scans the whole table - is this a bug or does only standard sql support sub-querying date-partitioned tables?

Comment: You could [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with a sample job ID.

Comment: any idea if this can be achieved when using explicit partition columns?

Comment: Yes, it should work in the same way. Try it and see! Click the check mark in the UI to see how many bytes will be processed by the query over the view before running it.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, will this work if you have a UNION ALL between two SELECT statements that both expose two different tables' partitioning pseudocolumns?  In other words, each SELECT uses _PARTITIONTIME and you extract it accordingly.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Hi, it doesn't seem to work with source table partitioned by an actual column instead of the default _PARTITIONTIME. I added a new column in the view with EXTRACT(DATE FROM my_partition_col) as new_partition_col, the amount of data queried on the same partition is way way larger than on the source table. So I don't think the view is using the partition correctly.

Comment: In my humble opinion, the query is a little bit misleading. It should read: `SELECT *, timestamp(EXTRACT(DATE FROM _PARTITIONTIME)) AS partition_date FROM \`date-partitioned-table\`;` as written in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63056957

Answer (score 10):

For anyone trying to do this with a wildcard partition date table such as Firebase or Google Analytics:

```
create view some.view as ( 
    select *, _TABLE_SUFFIX as suffix from 
    `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_*` 
)


 select * from some.view WHERE suffix = '20180814'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs to union several tables but can't use a wildcard table. You can add a fixed value column to each table. Filtering by this column reduces the scanned bytes.

```sql
CREATE VIEW some.view as ( 
  SELECT *, DATE('2023-01-01') as `date`, 
  FROM `my_project.my_dataset.some_table`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, DATE('2023-01-02') as `date`, 
  FROM `my_project.my_dataset.another_table`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, DATE('2023-01-03') as `date`, 
  FROM `my_project.my_dataset.again_another_table`
);


SELECT * FROM some.view WHERE `date` = '2023-01-03'
```