# how to create a view in big-query with date as an input?

Tags: google-bigquery

can anybody tell me whether there are anyways to create a 
Parameterized view in google big-query? so far what i searched in the net, i am not able to find any updates to achieve the same. I want to pass date values as parameter to my view, to do some aggregate operation based on the date supplied from ui.
Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/44781767/6253347 and see if it helps. While you can't make the date a "parameter" of the view, you can filter on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of early August 2017 - parameters in views are not supported.
From what I see in respective [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905221) -  instead of parametrized views BigQuery Team is looking of implementing more generic user defined TVFs.