# How to make views recognize partitioned column with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an `orders` table as:

```
orderid       purchase_date                 etl_timestamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------
120           2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC       2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC
120           2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC       2018-10-25 13:42:13 UTC
121           2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC       2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC
```

Every specific interval I load data to the table with `APPEND`. So this table contains versions of the same order.

The partition field is `purchase_date`.

In order to work with the data I have a view `production_orders` defined as:

```
select 
    orders_id, .... purchase_date, etl_timestamp
from
    (select
         * ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orders_id order by etl_timestamp DESC) as rn 
     from
         `PROJECT.DATASET.orders`) as t 
where 
    t.rn = 1
```

This returns the latest version of each order. For the above example it returns:

```
orderid       purchase_date                 etl_timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------
120           2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC       2018-10-25 13:42:13 UTC
121           2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC       2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC
```

This is great but when I run query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.production_orders`
WHERE purchase_date> '2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC'
```

It tells me that the `query will process 3.6 GB of data`.

The `orders` table is 3.6 GB - this means that the view does not consider the partition field.

To compare when I do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.orders`
WHERE purchase_date> '2018-10-25 13:40:48 UTC'
```

It tells me that `the query will process 945 KB data`

I read this [BigQuery Date-Partitioned Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781767/bigquery-date-partitioned-views)  but couldn't figure out how to use this in my case. My partition is a chosen field from the table it's not a metadata field. Also, I need the field as `TIMESTAMP` not as `DATE`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: not supported for view with custom partitioning field. only for pseudocolumn `_PARTITIONTIME` as of now

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant So what can I do? I don't have _PARTITIONTIME  on my table. It makes no scene for my queries.. I run queries on purchase date not on the date that the row added to the table.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant  Appending data and have multi versions for records is common practice for BigQuery users. How do you handle this if View option is not feasible ?

Comment: 1) if feature does not exists in BigQuery yet - you submit the feature request at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) but obviously you first check if such request already exists and if it is you star/vote it :o)  2) you look for workaround  - in your case you just simple don't use view that rely on partitioning with custom field and rather query original table

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I understand that view is not an option. I'm asking what is the solution? Many people use append and versioning on their tables. What is the recommended method to solve this?

Comment: the query you have that selects most recent version looks good to me  - not the best - but good. there are tons of posts here on SO about de-duping - check them pick what you like more and if still question(s) post new specific question and we will help :o)

Comment: My goal is to allow the users to query data without knowledge of the versioning. View solves this but it has huge costs so I drop this idea. I would appreciate any reference that you can give as I didn't find anything useful. Please not the rows are not identical there can be changes with order status or whatever this is not a cleaning table operation...

Answer (score 2):

When queries reach certain complexity, BigQuery is not able to pass outer query parameters into the inner queries - hence limiting the ability to use partition filtering from an outer query. This happens with views too.

To create something similar to a "materialized view", you could use the approach described on [I want a "materialized view" of the latest records](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52993916/132438).

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for me. My process is almost real-time. new records added every 3 minutes. reports running on the data all the time.

Comment: I thought of a way to solve this with a CREATE VIEW... will post later

Comment: again I don't see how the answer there helps me. What am I suppose to replace this code     `WHERE datehour > "2018-10-25"`   in my case? If you have a solution that can works in my case please add more details

Comment: So the question now is "how to write a script outside BigQuery that runs every day"? If the "schedule query" feature can't handle this, try apps script. For example, modify https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZkkKcT9yrcYc1g8QqJaIE6PJtoFig3G_ZNbtXuK6fw/edit. But let's save the details for a new question

Comment: @Luis, I updated my answer. No re-creation of the view is needed anymore

Comment: sorry I really don't understand how your query apply to my case. When did I say something about "outside BigQuery" ? The question is as I wrote. I have a table with appending data. I want to have something else table/View/whatever which I can access as: select * from ____  and it will give me the most updated row per id. that is it. I think my question explains it.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer? There's no "outside BigQuery"

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I don't understand your FROM & WHERE. I have one table. You have:      SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_vt.just_latest_rows`
    # previously "materialized" results
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
    # append-only table, source of truth
    WHERE datehour > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 2 DAY )      -   Please write your answer in the terms of my question.

Comment: To find my answer to your exact question, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52993961/132438. If that doesn't work, please try the alternatives I commented about here