# I want a "materialized view" of the latest records

Tags: google-bigquery

As I keep appending rows to BigQuery, I'd like to have a "materialized view" of the latest row for each id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2022 UPDATE: the answer might be OUTDATED given it was given before Materialized view release in 2018 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro
The following solution involves `Scheduled Queries`, still working as of 2022-03

2018-10: BigQuery doesn't support [materialized views](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996), but you can use this approach:

Let's say you want a table with the latest info for each row, and you want to keep it updated - so anyone querying can easily access the latest row without having to scan the whole append-only table.

For this example I'll use my [Wikipedia clustered logs](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b) - and I'll create a table with the latest rows of all English pages that start with 'A'. These restrictions make my queries faster and smaller for this demo purposes.

Let's create the table first:

```
CREATE TABLE `wikipedia_vt.just_latest_rows` AS
SELECT latest_row.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY datehour DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] latest_row
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` a
  WHERE datehour BETWEEN "2018-10-18" AND "2018-10-21" 
  AND wiki='en' AND title LIKE 'A%'
  GROUP BY title
)
```

And now I want to update it with all the new rows received since that date:

```
MERGE `wikipedia_vt.just_latest_rows` T
# our "materialized view"
USING  (
  SELECT latest_row.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY datehour DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] latest_row
    FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` a
    WHERE datehour > TIMESTAMP_SUB(@run_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
    # change to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or let scheduled queries do it
    AND datehour > '2000-01-01' # nag
    AND wiki='en' AND title LIKE 'A%'
    GROUP BY title
  )
) S
ON T.title = S.title

WHEN MATCHED THEN
  # if the row is there, we update the views and time
  UPDATE SET views = S.views, datehour=S.datehour

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  # if the row is not there, we insert it 
  INSERT (datehour, wiki, title, views) VALUES (datehour, wiki, title, views)
```

Now you should set up a process to run this query periodically. To keep querying costs down, make sure the process changes the starting date for updates.

A simple way to set up this process is to use the new BigQuery Scheduled Queries, which will replace @run_time with the current timestamp.

To create a view that combines this approach with a real-time view of the latest records, see:

- [I want "live materialized views", with the latest info for any row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999709/i-want-live-materialized-views-with-the-latest-info-for-any-row/52999710#52999710)

[image]

Comment: You can use the [scheduled query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) feature (currently in beta) for scheduling, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggested improvements Elliott!

Comment: There is a limit of the DML actions you can do per table per day. This isn't best practice if you need frequent updates of the "materialized view"

Comment: If frequent updates are a problem to deal with, see the answer to this question: "I want "live materialized views", with the latest info for any row" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999709/i-want-live-materialized-views-with-the-latest-info-for-any-row/52999710#52999710

Comment: BigQuery now supports materialized views:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro

Comment: @FelipeHoffa is there a way to achieve this in 2022 materialized view? That solution can be nice, at the same time the maintenance could be much simpler in case we have hundreds of tables to manage

Comment: I moved out of BigQuery and into Snowflake, so I apologize for not maintaining these answers!