# I want "live materialized views", with the latest info for any row

Tags: google-bigquery

I saw this solution as an alternative to materialized views:

- [I want a "materialized view" of the latest records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993916/i-want-a-materialized-view-of-the-latest-records)

But it's using the scheduled queries that run at most every 3 hours. My users are expecting live data, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2018-10: BigQuery doesn't support [materialized views](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62244996), but you can use this approach:

- [Use the previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993916/i-want-a-materialized-view-of-the-latest-records) to "materialize" a summary of the latest data, until the time that scheduled query ran.
- Create a view that combines the materialized data, with a live view of the latest data on the append-only table.

Code would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `wikipedia_vt.just_latest_rows_live` AS

SELECT latest_row.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY datehour DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] latest_row
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_vt.just_latest_rows`
    # previously "materialized" results
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018`
    # append-only table, source of truth
    WHERE datehour > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 2 DAY )

  ) a
  GROUP BY title
)
```

Note that BigQuery is able to use `TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 2 DAY )` to prune partitions effectively.