# Eliminate duplicates automatically from table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table will be getting new data everyday from source system and i want the duplicates to be deleted automatically as soon as new data gets loaded to table.

Is it possible in bigquery?

I tried to create a view named sites_view in bigquery with below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM prd.sites
```

but duplicates not getting deleted automatically.

Comment: What are you defining as a "duplicate?"  It may be appropriate to add some unique constraints to your table.  Or, we could try something else.  Please add information to your question.

Comment: @NikhilBOORLA . . . You can do this as part of the process that loads the table.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999709/i-want-live-materialized-views-with-the-latest-info-for-any-row

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery:

Duplicates will not be deleted automatically - there is no such functionality in BigQuery

You should have some process to make this happen as frequently as you need or use views

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery is based on `append-only` kind of a design. So, it accepts all the data. 
This is one of the reasons there are no Primary/Unique key constraints on it, so you can't prevent duplicates from entering in the table.

```
 So, you have to have a process like:
    1.) Create a new table without duplicates from your original table.
        (You can use DISTINCT/ROW_NUMBER() for doing this.)
    2.) Drop original table.
    3.) Rename new table with original table name.
```

Let me know if this information helps.

Comment: As I said above, duplicates don't get dropped magically. You would need to write an automated function/procedure. Just code the steps I told you in form of a `Function` and run it after your table gets loaded every time.