# Duplicates when streaming JSON data to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll

I am streaming data into a table on BigQuery but ran into a problem with duplicates. I read through the doc that said that specifying a `insertId` would prevent dupes but this insertId is only live for 5 minutes to 90 minutes. Afterwards if a row is pushed with that insertId, it gets inserted as a dupe. What is the best way to push data into my BigQuery table and avoid getting dupes?

Comment: Can you share more details? How much time would you like to wait for dupes? Are dupes really dupes, or do they contain different data? Is such, would you like to retain the latest version or the first one? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993916/i-want-a-materialized-view-of-the-latest-records/52993917#52993917

Comment: Let's say I push a row with an insertId of 'a1'. And then a week later, I try pushing with that same insertId but it doesn't update the original row but adds another one to the table. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Is one week the period you'd like to check for? What if it comes a month after? The solution will depend on which window you are thinking of. Thoughts about the link I gave in the previous comment?

Comment: Any time after the insertId has expired. I read that it can expire anywhere from 5 minutes to 90 minutes. Afterward it has expired, pushing a row with an insertId that was done in the past will be reinserted. Do you have any recommendation on how to prevent this?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa ^can recommendation?

Comment: I think the link in my first comment applies in that case