# Materialized view of first rows

Tags: google-bigquery

Supposing I have a table with columns `date | group_id | user_id | text`, and I would like to get the first 3 texts (by date) of each `group_id/user_id` pair.

It seems wasteful to query the whole table say, every 3 hours, as the results are unlikely to change for a given pair once set, so I looked at materialized views, but examples were about [single rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993916/i-want-a-materialized-view-of-the-latest-records), not sets of rows.

Another issue is that the `date` column does not correspond to the ingestion date, does this mean that I have to add an ingestion date column to be able to use the `@run_time` in scheduled queries?

Alternatively, would it be more sensible to load the batch on a separate table, compare it with/update the "first/materialized" table, before merging it with the main table? (so instead of having queries on the main table, fill the materialized table one preemptively at every load). This looks *hacky/wrong* though?

Answer (score 0):

The question links to [I want a "materialized view" of the latest records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993916/i-want-a-materialized-view-of-the-latest-records), and mentions that it deals with single rows instead of multiple rows. The question says that it wants the 3 latest rows instead of only one.

For that, look at the inner query in that answer. Instead of doing this:

```
  SELECT latest_row.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY datehour DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] latest_row
    FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` a
    WHERE datehour > TIMESTAMP_SUB(@run_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
    # change to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or let scheduled queries do it
    AND datehour > '2000-01-01' # nag
    AND wiki='en' AND title LIKE 'A%'
    GROUP BY title
  )
```

Do this:

```
  SELECT latest_row.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY datehour DESC LIMIT 3)[OFFSET(0)] latest_row
    FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018` a
    WHERE datehour > TIMESTAMP_SUB(@run_time, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
    # change to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or let scheduled queries do it
    AND datehour > '2000-01-01' # nag
    AND wiki='en' AND title LIKE 'A%'
    GROUP BY title
  )
```

Re `@run_time` - you can compare it to any column, just make sure to have a column that makes sense to the logic you want to implement.