# BigQuery querying _TABLE_SUFFIX in views with wildcard tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

***Summarised Question:***

How can I query a view that is based off a wildcard table using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` as a filter, rather than a column (which would query **all** the tables)?

e.g.

```
 SELECT Name, date, weight 
 FROM `my_view`
 WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '2020-01-01'
```

rather than

```
 SELECT Name, date, weight 
 FROM `my_view`
 WHERE date >= '2020-01-01'
```

***Detailed Question:***

Say I have a table `bq.school.weights_20191231` with the following format

```
| Name  | Date       | Weight |
|-------|------------|--------|
| Bob   | 2019-12-31 | 55kg   |
| Alex  | 2019-12-31 | 95kg   |
| ...   | ...        | ..     |
| Sandy | 2019-12-31 | 43kg   |
```

and a table `bq.school.weights_20200101`

```
| Name  | Date       | Weight |
|-------|------------|--------|
| Bob   | 2020-01-01 | 60kg   |
| Alex  | 2020-01-01 | 100kg  |
| ...   | ...        | ..     |
| Sandy | 2020-01-01 | 40kg   |
```

And I create a view based off the base table `bq.school.weights_*` called `weights_view`, e.g.

```
SELECT Name, Date, Weight 
FROM `bq.school.weights_*`
```

How can I query `weights_view` using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` to filter the date, rather than using `WHERE DATE = "2020-01-01"` (which would query all the tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution***

Similar to the [BigQuery Date-Partitioned Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781767/bigquery-date-partitioned-views) question, you need to expose the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` column, and then query off that, e.g.

```
SELECT Name, Weight, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS the_date
FROM `bq.school.weights_*
```

and then query the view with

```
SELECT *
FROM `weights_view`
WHERE the_date = "20200101"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @AH's answer, you can simply reference the ***_TABLE_SUFFIX*** within your ***WHERE*** statement without having to select it and query the view.

I must point that, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix), the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column contains the values matched by the table wildcard. Also, it does not need to be within the SELECT clause. Below there is an example using a public dataset, it scans two tables **gsod1940** and **gsod1944**,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  max,
  ROUND((max-32)*5/9,1) celsius,
  mo,
  da,
  year
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
WHERE
  ( _TABLE_SUFFIX = '1940'
    OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = '1944' )
ORDER BY
  max DESC
```

Notice that there is a pattern within the table's names ***noaa_gsod.gsod*** which is followed by a year. Also, pay attention that the pseudo column *_TABLE_SUFFIX* is not selected. Although you can select if you desire.

Lastly, I must stress that there are limitations for using wildcards with *_TABLE_SUFFIX*, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations):

> - The wildcard table functionality does not support views. If the wildcard table matches any view in the dataset, the query returns an
>   error. This is true whether or not your query contains a WHERE clause
>   on the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column to filter out the view.
> - Currently, cached results are not supported for queries against multiple tables using a wildcard even if the Use Cached Results option
>   is checked. If you run the same wildcard query multiple times, you are
>   billed for each query. Wildcard tables support native BigQuery storage
>   only. You cannot use wildcards when querying an external table or a
>   view.
> - Queries that contain Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements cannot use a wildcard table as the target of the query. For example, a
>   wildcard table may be used in the FROM clause of an UPDATE query, but
>   a wildcard table cannot be used as the target of the UPDATE operation.
> - Wildcard queries are not supported for tables protected by customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in the where clause

SELECT Name, Weight
FROM `bq.school.weights_*` WHERE _table_suffix >= "20200101"